# Connection pooling using perl DBI with postgresql

Tags: perl, postgresql, connection-pooling, dbi

i am using a perl script which inserts records into the database at every 5 minutes. Now when there is a lot of data available it might possible that number of connections made to the database increase thereby wasting my precious resources. So i want connection pooling mechanism to work with perl. I am using postgresql as my database. I googled it and i found some solutions like [i found such solutions but they didnot work for me](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2001-01/msg01362.php)

Can anyone please tell me how can i achieve connection pooling in perl?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also maintain persistent connection if so frequently used.

Comment: The stuff from the link you posted only works if you have mod_perl in use. If you use a cronjob (assumption) to insert data every 5 minutes, why does the number of connections increase? Is there so much data that 5 minutes isn't enough? If so, think about not starting the script as long as it is still running. Let it finish the first batch, then start with the next one.

Comment: @vjshah : that's what i am asking. i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @simbabque : i am not executing it as a cronjob. i am calling it as my wish. each time the script is called the connection will be created and after execution it will be released but it might possible that at a time there are hundreds instances of script running simultaneously so i want to implement an effective connection pooling mechanism which restrict the number of connections made to the database.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you cannot share a DBI instance/dbh between different processes. You might be able to realize it with a fork, though. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874434/how-can-i-share-a-database-connection-across-a-forked-process-in-perl. Still it's interesting that it takes so long. Maybe there is a way to optimize it so it runs faster?

Comment: Look at this link. hope this helps you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734289/how-can-i-have-dbic-persistent-database-connection-in-mod-perl

Comment: @vjshah: That is mod_perl again. I don't think he's using it because he said he's calling it 'as my wish'. Sounds like he just runs it from the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd restrict myself to a perl solution. Just install [pgbouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) and have it available to any clients you require.

Comment: what about MySQL?

Comment: The question isn't about MySQL